# Get cell phone manufacturer and model names with compact framework

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I would like to get the device manufacturer and model names programmatically with C# / .net compact framework, in a windows mobile phone.

For instance: I would like to know, in my program, if a device is a "Samsung some_model_name" or an "HTC yet_another_model_name", or if code is running in emulator. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using SystemParametersInfoString method from coredll.dll.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);

    if (SystemParametersInfoString(SPI_GETPLATFORMTYPE, sb.Capacity, sb, 0) != 0)
    {
        String name = sb.ToString();        
    }
```

Comment: just changed SPI_GETPLATFORMTYPE to SPI_GETOEMINFO, but thanks for the answer!